# How to create query with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

Please help me. I can not create query from native sql using spring data.
How do I convert the following expression?

```
select distinct brand, model from cars 
where brand like '%:query%' or model like '%:query%' limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

that helped me, hopefully you too

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/

Comment: thanks, I read this article, but did not know how to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) with Spring Data JPA, something of the likes of:

```
interface SimpleCar {
    String getBrand();
    String getModel();
}
```

and then:

```
List<SimpleCar> findDistinctByBrandLikeOrModelLike(String query);
```

You can review [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) for different options to query a DB with some examples.

By the way, if you want to see what queries your methods are executing you can activate DEBUG logging mode in log4j for `org.springframework` package or `org.hibernate` (if you're using Hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Query("select distinct brand, model from cars " +
       "where brand like %:query% or model like %:query% limit 2")
public List<Car> find(@Param("query") String query);
```

Basically what you had but without the speech marks.